# Windows 8.1 hp laptop won't connect to wifi.

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, windows-8.1

I recently came abroad with my family and am staying at a family members house while I'm here. Their wifi (a BT home hub router) has a password (wpa2), which I know. However, every time I try and connect, my laptop will say "checking network requirements" then simply tell me I "can't connect to this network". It doesn't even ask me to input the password. Everyone else here  has no trouble getting on and has no idea why the router is rejecting me. This is starting to annoy me as I'll be here for a while, any suggestions or fixes?

Comment: Have you tried Google? I found [this link](http://www.windows8core.com/solve-cant-connect-network-wi-fi-error-windows-8-1-easily/) and others on my first search.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I must have missed it somehow. Sorry about making you take time to fix my overlook. Want to post the link as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this link](http://www.windows8core.com/solve-cant-connect-network-wi-fi-error-windows-8-1-easily/), which lists 4 possible ways of tackling the problem.

The last solution (router problem) can be discounted, as everyone else is working fine.

The first (forget/reconnect) seems worth trying first, then the third (Windows Network Diagnostics). If all else fails, the second (reboot) is always a good last resort, but make sure it is a full restart by shutting down first.